# Extraction text php

Tags: php, function, text-extraction

I have this a file named "test.txt" which has the following content:

```
BEGIN_SESSION 7
1h+ 47
30mn-1h 20
15mn-30mn 16
5mn-15mn 43
2mn-5mn 29
30s-2mn 35
0s-30s 170
END_SESSION
```

and I would like a function that extract it data and I'd like for "30s-2mn" and "0s-30s" to be add it value for example it'll be in the end "35+170=205"
And I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work :

```
preg_match("/BEGIN_SESSION(.*)END_SESSION/is", $test, $matches);
$session = $matches[0] ;
preg_match('/^30s-2mn ([0-9]{14}) /ms', $test, $matches); 
$data= $matches;
var_dump($data);
```

What's the problem in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there's a mistake in your PHP, for your second `preg_match`you again use `$test` as subject instead of `$session`.

Second your RegEx simply can't match. The caret (`^`) tells PHP to start the search at the beginning of the test subject but there's no `30s...`, this `30s...` is somewhere in the test string.  So remove that. And then you tell PHP there are 14 numbers from 0-9, but you are just looking for two. So a working RegEx would be:

```
/30s-2mn ([0-9]{2})/ms
```

Corrected:

```
preg_match("/BEGIN_SESSION(.*)END_SESSION/is", $test, $matches);
$session = $matches[0] ;
preg_match('/30s-2mn ([0-9]{2})/ms', $session, $matches); 
$data= $matches;
var_dump($data);
```

What prints out:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "30s-2mn 35" [1]=> string(2) "35" }
```

And now do some maths:

```
preg_match("/BEGIN_SESSION(.*)END_SESSION/is", $test, $matches);
$session = $matches[0];
preg_match('/30s-2mn ([0-9]{2})/ms', $session, $matches); 
$a = $matches[1];
preg_match('/0s-30s ([0-9]{3})/ms', $session, $matches); 
$b = $matches[1];

var_dump($a+$b);
```

prints:

```
 int(205)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your observations!

Comment: Could you please take a look in this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887606/extract-file-in-php-and-display-content-in-chart
And thanks very much