# Extract file in PHP and display content in chart

Tags: php, function, pie-chart, text-extraction

I have this a file named "test.txt" which has the following content:

```
BEGIN_SESSION 7
1h+ 47
30mn-1h 20
15mn-30mn 16
5mn-15mn 43
2mn-5mn 29
30s-2mn 35
0s-30s 170
END_SESSION
```

And thanks to the user [wumm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1779477/wumm) it help me to find a way to extract the data and display it.So the problem is :I've witten this function that display data in a pie chart :

```
function awstats_extract_session($session)
{
# Session range - Number of visits

$session = explode("\n", $session) ; 
unset($session[(count($session)-1)]) ; 
unset($session[0]) ; 
$sessions = array();
foreach ($session as $key => $value) {
    $session[$key] = explode(" ", $value) ;
    //print_array($session[$key]);
    $sessions[] = array($session[$key][0],$session[$key][1]) ; 
}
$sessions = json_encode($sessions, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) ; 


?>
<div id="collapse_awstats_extract_session" class="accordion-body collapse in">
    <div class="accordion-inner">
        <div id="chart-session" style="height:350px; width:700px; margin:0 auto;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      var data = <?php echo $sessions; ?>;
      var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot('chart-session', [data], {
        title: 'Durée des visites',
        seriesDefaults: {
          renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer, 
          rendererOptions: {
            showDataLabels: true,
          },
        }, 
        legend: { show:true, location: 'e' },           
      });
    });
</script>
```

And there's a function that calls that previous one :

```
 <?php
            echo '<div class="accordion-group">';

            preg_match("/BEGIN_SESSION(.*)END_SESSION/is", $awstats, $matches);
            $session = $matches[0];
            preg_match('/30s-2mn ([0-9]{2})/ms', $session, $matches); 
            $a = $matches[1];
            preg_match('/0s-30s ([0-9]{3})/ms', $session, $matches); 
            $b = $matches[1];

            var_dump($a+$b);



            awstats_title("<a class='accordion-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion_awstats_navigation' href='#collapse_awstats_extract_session'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down'></span> Durée des visites</a>", "session") ;
            awstats_extract_session($session) ;
```

And i would like that display all it content but the last two "30s-2mn 35" "0s-30s 170"
I'd like to diplay it as "0s-2mn 205".Please Help
P.S:
Or is there a way to change the file "test.txt" in such to have "test2.txt":

```
BEGIN_SESSION 7
1h+ 47
30mn-1h 20
15mn-30mn 16
5mn-15mn 43
2mn-5mn 29
0s-2mn 205
END_SESSION
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would like to help you but I'm not sure what your question is. Could you please try to rephrase your actual question.

Comment: Is there a way to edit the first file "test.txt" in order to have it as "test2.txt"?
so that when i call $session it calls the second file !!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
preg_match("/BEGIN_SESSION(.*)END_SESSION/is", $test, $matches);
$session = $matches[0];
preg_match('/30s-2mn ([0-9]{2})/ms', $session, $matches); 
$a = $matches[1];
preg_match('/0s-30s ([0-9]{3})/ms', $session, $matches); 
$b = $matches[1];

$session = preg_replace('/30s-2mn ([0-9]{2})\n0s-30s ([0-9]{3})/ms', "0s-2mn " . ($a+$b), $session);
```

Then `$session` contains the text you showed in the last code example in your question. To write it out you could do.

`$session` now contains:

```
BEGIN_SESSION 7
1h+ 47
30mn-1h 20
15mn-30mn 16
5mn-15mn 43
2mn-5mn 29
0s-2mn 205
END_SESSION
```

Comment: Sorry! but the preg_replace() function didn't seem to replace the data i don't knw why! it still the same!

Comment: If I use this code outputs the output into the files `test2.txt`

Comment: Sorry! but i want the data in `$session`! is there a way ?

Comment: Of course just change $n to $session in the last line of the first code piece. I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: I am very sorry to bother you but when i try to `var_dump($session);`
it display me this :
`string(111) "BEGIN_SESSION 7 1h+ 47 30mn-1h 20 15mn-30mn 16 5mn-15mn 43 2mn-5mn 29 30s-2mn 35 0s-30s 170 END_SESSION"` Idon't know where's the problem ?

Comment: I'm testing with this code: http://pastebin.com/wXE7J6UH That should work at you, doesn't it? So there must be something I've overseen in your question, can you see what it is?

Comment: The thing is that i have a file that put in `$awstats` that have all the data and I've change the `$test` into `$awstats`.So i don't want the primary file to change or generate another one I just like if it can diplay this `"BEGIN_SESSION 7 1h+ 47 30mn-1h 20 15mn-30mn 16 5mn-15mn 43 2mn-5mn 29 0s-2mn 205 END_SESSION"` when i try `var_dump($session);` !